# Unable to parse xml attributes without using namespace while parsing using Groovy

Tags: xml, groovy, xml-parsing, xml-namespaces, xmlslurper

I have an xml response which looks like :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <multiRef xmlns:ns9="http://hero.ar.vixo.in" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" id="id2" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns9:IdentityModel">
         <vixId xsi:type="xsd:int">13364719</vixId>
      </multiRef>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This response is stored in a `String` name `xmlMsg`
I am trying to parse it as follows:-

```
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlMsg);
def vixId = xml.Body.multiRef.vixId.text()
```

But the problem here is that before reading `vixId` i want to verify if 'type' in `multiRef` tag is `IdentityModel`

I tried accessing `type` as follows, but in vain :-

```
def vixId = xml.Body.multiRef.@type.text()
```

Please note that i am able to access `id` in `multiRef` tag using as follows:-

```
 def vixId = xml.Body.multiRef.@id.text()
```

Please help me in accessing `type` in `multiRef` tag

Please note that i want to parse the `type` in `multiRef` tag without using name space like `multiRef.'@xsi:type'` because my `namespace` could change. All i want is that `multiRef` tag has a attribute `type` and that has a value of `IdentityModel`.. Only if this is there then I want to read `vixId`.
Also note that with groovy 1.8 i was parsing it without namespace using `multiRef.@type` but it has stopped working ever since i updated groovy to 2.4.7

The way i was parsing it with groovy 1.8  is :

```
def xml = new XmlSlurper(factory.newSAXParser().getXMLReader()).parseText(xmlMsg)
idModel = xml.Body.multiRef.@type.text()
```

PS:- I am fairly new in dealing with xmls